# Calculating difference of timestamps grouped by day

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a Pandas Series consisting of datetime entries. For example

```
timestamps = [datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 25, 22, 00), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 25, 23, 55), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 26, 7, 7), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 26, 7, 30), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 26, 12, 22)]
df = pd.Series(timestamps)
```

With `df.dt.normalize().value_counts()` I can print the number of timestamps per day. But now I would like also to output the differences (in min) of the timestamps per day, so for example

```
*** 2020, 7, 25 ***
115
*** 2020, 7, 26 ***
432
27
292
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Is your expected output correct? how do you get `432` for `2020, 7, 26` , I am a little unclear on that

Comment: @anky from datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 25, 23, 55) to datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 26, 7, 7) it is 432 min.

Comment: that is the same logic without grouping: `df.diff().dt.total_seconds().div(60)` whereas the title says *grouped by day*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group on date and get difference then convert to minutes using `dt.total_seconds().div(60)`

```
out = (df.to_frame('DateTime').assign(Time_diff=df.groupby(df.dt.date).diff()
      .dt.total_seconds().div(60)))
```

---

```
             DateTime  Time_diff
0 2020-07-25 22:00:00        NaN
1 2020-07-25 23:55:00      115.0
2 2020-07-26 07:07:00        NaN
3 2020-07-26 07:30:00       23.0
4 2020-07-26 12:22:00      292.0
```

For a dictionary, you can use:

```
d = {i:g.diff().dt.total_seconds().div(60).dropna().tolist() 
  for i,g in df.groupby(df.dt.date)}

{datetime.date(2020, 7, 25): [115.0], datetime.date(2020, 7, 26): [23.0, 292.0]}
```

EDIT:

Per comments, you can follow same logic without groupby:

```
df.dt.date.to_frame("Date").assign(Time_diff=df.diff().dt.total_seconds().div(60))
         Date  Time_diff
0  2020-07-25        NaN
1  2020-07-25      115.0
2  2020-07-26      432.0
3  2020-07-26       23.0
4  2020-07-26      292.0
```

Comment: Thank you. But how also to get the 432min which are going over midnight?

Comment: @machinery that is the same logic without grouping: `df.diff().dt.total_seconds().div(60)` whereas the title says *grouped by day*